# ZF2 - autoloader classmap Fatal Error 'Map file provided does not exist'

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-autoloader

I just started Learning Zend Framework but I am having problem with my modules.
Please see the below error. I don't know what else to show you yet for further infomation.
Please let me know what I need to show you to solve the problem.

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Loader\Exception\InvalidArgumentException**

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'Zend\Loader\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Map
> file provided does not exist. Map file: "C:\Program
> Files\xampp\htdocs\zend_intro\module\Album/autoload_classmap.php"' in
> C:\Program
> Files\xampp\htdocs\zend_intro\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader.php:175
> Stack trace: #0 C:\Program
> Files\xampp\htdocs\zend_intro\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader.php(85):
> Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader->loadMapFromFile('C:\Program File...')
>  #1 C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\zend_intro\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader.php(121):
> Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader->registerAutoloadMap('C:\Program
> File...') #2 C:\Program
> Files\xampp\htdocs\zend_intro\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader.php(64):
> Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader->registerAutoloadMaps(Array) #3
> C:\Program
> Files\xampp\htdocs\zend_intro\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Lo
> in C:\Program
> Files\xampp\htdocs\zend_intro\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader.php
> on line 175
> ```

Answer (score 9):

If you've copied example code from a module that actually used the `autoload_classmap.php` file, then you probably have something like this in your **module.config.php** file or somewhere in your **Module.php** file:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(  // THIS IS
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php'      // THE PROBABLE
        ),                                          // CULPRIT
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__
            )
        )
    );
}
```

The solution?  Either remove those lines of code - *you are not required to have an autoloader classmap for each module* - or actually [*create a classmap*](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/using-zendloaderautoloader/).

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called **autoload_classmap.php** under **zend_intro/module/Album** and include this line of code:

```
return array();
```

Check this on the documentation for more details
[Autoloading files](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

in **module.config.php** remove the **ClassMapAutoLoader** mapping, it should only have the StandardAutoloader as shown below;

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

This will solve the issue.